# Is there a way to run parameterized update statements using only DB2 commandline and bash?

Tags: performance, db2, prepared-statement

[DB2 LUW 10.5] I need to update a few hundred thousand rows in a DB2 table. Individual update statements will take longer to execute compared to precompiled approach. I cannot use perl or any such scripting tools with ODBC/JDBC/CLI and *PreparedStatement.executeUpdate* etc. due to certain limitations.

Is there a way to accomplish this using the db2 commandline tool and procedural SQL? My tool set is restricted to bash, SQL and DB2 Command line interface.

Comment: What is "parameterized approach" that you speak of, and why do you think it will be better than individual update statements? Won't your parameterized statements be individual as well?

Comment: I am looking to see  if there is any available option in the command line tool similar to the JDBC 'preparedstatement' that improves performance for repeated statements. from docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html : ".. the PreparedStatement object contains not just a SQL statement, but a SQL statement that has been precompiled. This means that when the PreparedStatement is executed, the DBMS can just run the PreparedStatement SQL statement without having to compile it first."

Comment: Can you give an example of what your data, table and update statement looks like?

Comment: It is a simple update statment like "update TableA set col1=null where colB=? and colC=?" but there are quite a few records. I don't want to run using a sinlge update statment (and loading values in where clause into a temp table etc.) because of locks on other transactions. I can use some ETL tool available here but I am too lazy to jump through hoops and wanted to see if there are any feature in the regular SQL commandline tool that I don't know of.

Comment: How do you know the values of colB and colC?

Comment: It is the result from another slightly long running query. I exported that to a file for  verifying, and I am planning to use it for the update step -probably bash+SQL statements or loading into a temp table - if I can't find any better ways

Answer (score 2):

If you are on 10.1 or later you can use `INGEST`. It is almost as fast as load, more feature rich and has less impact on a running system. First, you need to enable it by creating control tables (if you haven't already):

```
db2 'call sysproc.sysinstallobjects ( 'INGEST' ,'C' , null, null )';
```

Now you can ingest the data like:

```
db2 "ingest from file tab1.del 
 format delimited (
     $colb ...,
     $colc ...
 ) update tableA set colA = null 
   where (colb, colc) = ($colb, $colc)"
```

Here is an developerworks article:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1304ingestcmd/index.html

and here is the documentation:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0057198.html